# How to modify css class of container for specific element ID

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to modify class of an element for specific parent. Here is what I have:

```
<form id="form2">
    <div class="blueform">
        <div class="formlegend">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I would like to override class `formlegend` only for form with id "form2". I have tried:

```
#form2.formlegend {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

but it does not work. Is this even possible?

Comment: make sure this appears below your .formlegend defenition also I think you may need a space between the id and the class (although I'm not sure hence why im not putting as an answer)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are missing the "[descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators)" (whitespace, usually just a single space character) between the 2 selectors:

```
#form2 .formlegend {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Without the descendant combinator, your selector will match an element with an ID of `form2` *and* a class of `formlegend`. According to the markup in your question, you need it to match an element with the class `formlegend` that is a *descendant* of an element with an ID of `form2`.

Comment: Thumbs up for the space missing :)

Comment: Indeed space was only issue. Thank you for lighting fast answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but make sure your override class is declared **after** your originale class in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
#form2 .blueform .formlegend { }
```

if this does't work, you have to add additional element with unique ID ( ID always should be unique ). Two ID call override one ID call so it would look like

```
#override #form2 .formlegend { }
```